# How do you reference a field in the Embedded Code of an SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

Is there a proper way to reference the fields of a ssrs report from the embedded code of an ssrs report?

When I try to use `Fields!Program.Value` I get the following error --

> *There is an error on line 3 of custom code: [BC30469]
>
>       Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.*

Upon googling I found you could reference the Parameters of a report by prepending `Report.` at the beginning. So I tried this `Report.Fields.Program.Value`.

That results in the following error...

> *There is an error on line 3 of custom code: [BC30456] 'Fields' is not a member of 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ExprHostObjectModel.IReportObjectModelProxyForCustomCode'.*

So... in summary, is there a way to reference the fields from the embedded code. I figured out I could pass the field vals to the function itself but I would prefer to reference the fields directly.

Seth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass it in as a parameter.

[=Code.ToUSD(Fields!StandardCost.Value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798.aspx)

Comment: Thanks...that's what I needed to know.
Seth

Comment: It makes no sense to me that in reporting services, a parameter can be accessed directly while a field must be passed in.  It would be more consistent if either, a parameter could not be accessed directly or a field could be accessed directly. Regardless, @gbn Thank you for the answer and @Seth Spearman thank you for the question.

Comment: @Michael Eakins: It makes sense for datasets. A parameter is single, scalar and discrete so can be accessed universally. If you have a 1000 data rows, how do you know which text box in which row belongs to the data in that row? This syntax makes it explicit and less error-prone

Comment: I was thinking to narrowly, your scenario makes it clear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You do have two other alternatives to passing by parameter, though neither is very pretty.

*(Beware! After I wrote the following paragraph I discovered defaults from queries are not supported in local processing mode so this first solution may not be viable for you as it was not for me.)*

You can create a hidden report parameter with a default value set from a dataset, then reference this with the `Report.Parameters!MyParam.Value` syntax. You have to be careful when testing this, as (at least in BI studio 2005) the report parameters don't seem to get reliably re-initialised from the DB in the Preview tab.

Alternatively you can create a hidden textbox on the report with its text set from a dataset, and then reference the textbox from code. In this case you have to pass the `ReportItems` object as a parameter, but the slight advantage is that it is only ever one extra parameter. Be sure to strongly type the parameter when declaring it:

```
public Sub MyCustomCode(ri as ReportItems)
```

The code will work in BI studio without the type declaration but for me it caused errors with the report viewer control in local processing mode if '`as ReportItems`' was not present.

In either case, this is only really useful for page level data, so functions for use in a table should still take parameters.